# How to configure Mailsac (a disposable email server)?

Tags: linux, node.js

Has anybody set up Mailsac on a server (Linux and/or Windows)? On the Mailsac GitHub page it says just change `config.js` file. Does anybody have detailed instructions or an example of a `config.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Ubuntu installation script](https://github.com/ruffrey/mailsac/blob/master/install/ubuntu-1404.sh) as reference.
And looks like config file that you looking for is [mailsac.conf](https://github.com/ruffrey/mailsac/blob/master/install/mailsac.conf)